# Running Apple's default Action Extension code raises an exception or does nothing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-extensions

When I attempt to run Apple's default code for an Action Extension, it either does nothing or crashes. How can I fix these two bugs?

### Setup

1. Create a new Action Extension target in Xcode 7 (Language = Swift, Action Type = No User Interface)
2. Run the extension in the simulator, choosing Safari as the app to run.
3. Navigate to https://google.com in Safari
4. Invoke the extension you just created (you will need to tap the More button to enable it in the activities sheet).

### Bug 1: `extensionContext` is `nil`

Tap the action button, then the extension button between 1-5 times in Safari. Eventually the extension will crash on this line:

```
self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems([resultsItem], completionHandler: nil)
```

The log will say:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The exception is: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`

The reason is that `extensionContext` is `nil`.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

### Bug 2: When it doesn't crash, it doesn't do anything

When the app doesn't crash, nothing seems to happen. Based off of the code, it seems like the background color should have changed to red or green, yet that doesn't happen on any of the websites I have tried it on.

Are there any examples of websites where you have seen it work? How can I improve the code to make it actually do something?

---

### Things I have tried

#### Attempt 1: Pass in the context

Since the code is run inside a block, instead of referencing the context via self.extensionContext, I tried passing it in to the functions that need it (`itemLoadCompletedWithPreprocessingResults(_:context:)` and `doneWithResults(_:context:)`).

This seems to be more stable (it's only crashed once so far), but it still doesn't modify the background color.

---

### Reference

For reference, here is the default code for `ActionRequestHandler.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class ActionRequestHandler: NSObject, NSExtensionRequestHandling {

    var extensionContext: NSExtensionContext?

    func beginRequestWithExtensionContext(context: NSExtensionContext) {
        // Do not call super in an Action extension with no user interface
        self.extensionContext = context

        var found = false

        // Find the item containing the results from the JavaScript preprocessing.
        outer:
            for item: AnyObject in context.inputItems {
                let extItem = item as! NSExtensionItem
                if let attachments = extItem.attachments {
                    for itemProvider: AnyObject in attachments {
                        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(String(kUTTypePropertyList)) {
                            itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(String(kUTTypePropertyList), options: nil, completionHandler: { (item, error) in
                                let dictionary = item as! [String: AnyObject]
                                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                                    self.itemLoadCompletedWithPreprocessingResults(dictionary[NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingResultsKey] as! [NSObject: AnyObject])
                                }
                                found = true
                            })
                            if found {
                                break outer
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

        if !found {
            self.doneWithResults(nil)
        }
    }

    func itemLoadCompletedWithPreprocessingResults(javaScriptPreprocessingResults: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {
        // Here, do something, potentially asynchronously, with the preprocessing
        // results.

        // In this very simple example, the JavaScript will have passed us the
        // current background color style, if there is one. We will construct a
        // dictionary to send back with a desired new background color style.
        let bgColor: AnyObject? = javaScriptPreprocessingResults["currentBackgroundColor"]
        if bgColor == nil ||  bgColor! as! String == "" {
            // No specific background color? Request setting the background to red.
            self.doneWithResults(["newBackgroundColor": "red"])
        } else {
            // Specific background color is set? Request replacing it with green.
            self.doneWithResults(["newBackgroundColor": "green"])
        }
    }

    func doneWithResults(resultsForJavaScriptFinalizeArg: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) {
        if let resultsForJavaScriptFinalize = resultsForJavaScriptFinalizeArg {
            // Construct an NSExtensionItem of the appropriate type to return our
            // results dictionary in.

            // These will be used as the arguments to the JavaScript finalize()
            // method.

            let resultsDictionary = [NSExtensionJavaScriptFinalizeArgumentKey: resultsForJavaScriptFinalize]

            let resultsProvider = NSItemProvider(item: resultsDictionary, typeIdentifier: String(kUTTypePropertyList))

            let resultsItem = NSExtensionItem()
            resultsItem.attachments = [resultsProvider]

            // Signal that we're complete, returning our results.
            self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems([resultsItem], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            // We still need to signal that we're done even if we have nothing to
            // pass back.
            self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler: nil)
        }

        // Don't hold on to this after we finished with it.
        self.extensionContext = nil
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here.. Actually, I can run my project on simulator, but this problem occur only when I try to run the project on device. And I found this is not because i'm using swift 2, because I rewrite all extension code in objC as well, and it is not working too.